# Searching Tables and Columns in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

It is always handy to search tables and column in metadata. How do I search for tables in Hive based on th column name?

I know we can do via metadata. I logged into MySQL metadata but did not find a way to search.

I saw a way to search a column name but could not find a way to relate to table name.

```
select COLUMN_NAME from COLUMNS_V2 where column_name regexp 'repo' ;
```

I also searched on TBLS table, but there is no column name.