# How can I find a particular column name within all tables in Hive.?

Tags: hadoop, hive

How can I find a particular column name within all tables in Hive?

I ran this query in hive: `select table_name,column_name from retail.columns where column_name like '%emp%';` (*retail* is a database).

But it's giving:

> error FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Table not found 'columns'

I tried query: `select distinct table_name from default.columns where column_name = 'emp'` (*default* is mine database). But it's also giving error.

I searched about these, I got which query I wrote it's for SQL databases.

But I want to search in hive database? How to get in hive?

The same question has been asked before but I feel things might have changed and there might be direct solution:

[How can you search for all tables with a given column name and return which tables have this column name in Hadoop/Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273589/how-can-you-search-for-all-tables-with-a-given-column-name-and-return-which-tabl)

[Searching Tables and Columns in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569359/searching-tables-and-columns-in-hive)

Comment: _"which query I wrote it's for SQL databases"_ >> do you really believe there is a concept of **generic SQL database**?!? When it comes to accessing metadata, each DBMS has its own way -- some support `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, some support `sys`, some support `SYSTEM` -- and Hive supports *nothing*. At least from the SQL prompt. You have to tap the Metastore service with its (undocumented) Java API. Or possibly the Metastore database (stored in Derby or MySql or Postgres or whatever) except the schema is not documented either.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter The ER diagram for the metastore is on the wiki.  
 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+MetastoreAdmin#AdminManualMetastoreAdmin-MetastoreSchemaConsistencyandUpgrades PDF: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12471108/HiveMetaStore.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

below shell script will give you desired result:

```
hive -S -e 'show databases'|
while read database
do
   eval "hive -S -e 'show tables in $database'"|
   while read line
   do
if eval "hive -S -e 'describe $database.$line'"| grep -q "<column_name"; then
  output="Required table name: $database.$line"'\n';
else
output=""'\n';

fi
echo -e "$output"
 done
done
```

Comment: It's working fine if we already know the database name. But if we don't know the database name, then how can we find the table name.? And one more concern is above query is working very slow.If we will perform this scripting in large database it will take a lots of time. Can we increase the performance..?

Comment: @mohit.kc   I have adapted the script to scan all the database present in hive and further scan all tables present in that database. Did few modifcations to cater performance boost as well. Hopefully, this script will serve your need

Comment: Welcome Mohit :)

Comment: Hi @AbhishekAnand , Hope you are doing good. The code not go in loop if I change first line to hive -S -e 'show databases like 'abc_xyz%''| Can you please help to fix this issue?                                       Reason :  Actual Database number is more than 2000, if I filter by show databases like 'abc_xyz%' it will be only 50 Databases. pls let me know is there a way to achieve it in the above shell?

Answer (score 0):

I have written this below simplified shell script to get the result:

Step 1: Replace the <DB_NAME>, <COLUMN_NAME> in below script and run:

```
   while read line
   do
    if eval "hive -S -e 'describe <DB_NAME>.$line'"| grep -q "<COLUMN_NAME>"; then
        output="${output}  <DB_NAME>.$line"'\n';
    fi
   done < <(eval "hive -S -e 'show tables in <DB_NAME>'")
```

Step 2: Run the below command

```
echo -e "Required table name:\n\n $output"
```

**Note**: Remember to clear the variable output in case you are running multiple times.

```
output=""
```

Answer (score 0):

metastore table:
"TBLS","SDS","COLUMNS_V2"

to query columns of table:

```
select tc.* from "TBLS" tt 
inner join "SDS" ts on tt."SD_ID" = ts."SD_ID" 
inner join "COLUMNS_V2" tc on tc."CD_ID" = ts."CD_ID"
where tt."TBL_NAME"='test_fenqu'
order by "INTEGER_IDX"
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this query will help you if you know little bit name of your column :

```
select table_name,column_name from information_schema.columns
where column_name like '%lead%'
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's the query you can use on the metastore:

select TBL_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, TYPE_NAME from TBLS left join COLUMNS_V2 on CD_ID = TBL_ID where COLUMN_NAME like 'column';

where 'column' is the column name you're looking for.

Comment: columns are not apparently linked to tables via CD_ID, it doesn't match up with TBL_ID. Not that I would have expected it to, given the names...