# Information Schema HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveql, information-schema

I am working on HIVE and using DBVisualizer. I want to get all the table which has a particular column in a database.

```
For example : If there is a database which has a 2 tables:
Table_1 :
Columns:
A
B
ABC_ID
ABC_DT
C

Table_2 :
Columns :
C
D
ABC_X
ABC_Y
```

I want to get a list of tables and corresponding columns which contains a substring "BC_" and also if I can add a filter for database that would be helpful.
I know how to do this in SQL server, but on hive I am not able to figure this out.

Comment: you might need to write a shell to do this.. could be a possible way to do this.

Comment: see link below. it has exactly the same solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321736/how-can-i-find-a-particular-column-name-within-all-tables-in-hive